# How to identify the user from the User Token in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I followed [this link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Token+API) and I could get the user token. My use case is: Request get forward to `wso2 esb` from `wso2 api manager` with the Authorization header which has the user token. In side ESB I need to get the user details using the user access token. I have configured `wso2 is` as the key manager with `wso2 api manager`. If the way to get the information is accessing the db then which table should contain these data in which database?(May be using a class mediator), Or is there any other way to get this task done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get the token from `ACCESS_TOKEN` table of the `apimgt` db, which is created according to guide [IS as the Key Manager](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+the+Key+Manager)